# Properly extract string from router.query

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an application where I load articles and upon selecting one I pass the ID using `useRouter` so I can find the details of the articles with that id.

So this all works, if I select the article with ID 1 it goes to `article/1` and if I say  `{ articleDetails }` I get 1(Or whatever ID I pass.

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const { articleDetails } = router.query;
```

Now in my project I have the following to find the article based on the ID

```
 const articleData = data.project.find(
    (post) => post.id.toString() === { articleDetails }.toString();
  );
```

However, this does not work as nothing is found. however if I change `{ articleDetails }.toString();` to `"1"` it works just fine.
Was hoping I would be assisted in comparing this correctly.

regards

Comment: And if you just left it as `post.id` does the `{ articleDetails }` now also work without being "stringified"? I suspect it won't since you're using strict equality (`===`), so both types need to match along with *actually* referring to the same object in memory. This is probably why the serialization out to a string is working for you.

Comment: @DrewReese Error `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and '{ articledetails: string | string[] | undefined; }' have no overlap.`
I used `post.id == { articledetails }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const { articleDetails } = router.query;
```

Here, `{ articleDetails }` destructures the `router.query` object to get the `articleDetails` variable, Which I suppose is a string id.

Try

```
(post) => post.id.toString() === String(articleDetails);
```